# Automatic refresh of a web page

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi3

This my code which detects the position of the baby and insert it into my database which is consist of only 1 row. I use limit to delete the old row and remain the latest row.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "raspberry", "cribdb")

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN) #Right level-1
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN) #Right level-2
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN) #Right level-3

last_status = None

while True:

input12 = GPIO.input(12)

input16 = GPIO.input(16)

input18 = GPIO.input(18)

if (input12 == 1 and input16 == 0 and input18 == 0):
    status = "Lying down"
elif (input12 == 1 and input16 == 1 and input18 == 0):
    status = "Sitting"
elif (input12 == 1 and input16 == 1 and input18 == 1):
    status = "Standing"
elif (input12 == 0 and input16 == 1 and input18 == 1):
    status = "Trying to climb out"
elif (input12 == 0 and input16 == 0 and input18 == 1):
    status = "Almost out" 
else:
    status = "Out of the crib"

time.sleep(1)
if status != last_status:
    print(status)
    last_status = status
    curs = db.cursor()
    curs.execute(
    """INSERT INTO tbstatus values(NULL, %s)""", (status,)
)
db.commit()

number_of_rows= curs.execute("SELECT * FROM tbstatus")

if (number_of_rows >= 2:
    curs.execute("""DELETE FROM tbstatus order by id LIMIT 1""")
    db.commit()
    print("\n 1st row deleted ")
```

This is my code in PHP that displays the data from the database. It simply gets the values of the status in database and display it on a web page.

```
<?php require("connection.php"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <title> BABY MONITORING SYSTEM </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <?php  

        $sql_cmd = "SELECT * FROM tbstatus ORDER BY id desc";

        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql_cmd);

        $stmt->execute();


        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>STATUS OF THE BABY: </td>";
        echo "</tr>";


        while ($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $result['status'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        }

        echo "</table>";
    ?>

</div>

</body>
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

How the web page will reload once my database get a new status from my sensors?

Comment: use websockets, sse or ajax polling

Answer (score 1):

You will need to instruct the client (i.e. the browser) to fetch new data from the server. The simplest way is to tell the browser to refresh the page every so often, using (for example) the following code in the `<head>` of the html:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15">
```

The value in the `content` is the number of seconds between refreshes, so in this case the page would refresh every 15 seconds. You can, of course adjust this to your needs.

If you need more advanced reloading, you will have to use javascript to reload the page or refresh part of your page, but that might be overkill if this is a simple hobby project — just refreshing might be effective enough.

EDIT: the `head` part of your page would then look like this:

```
<head>
    <title> BABY MONITORING SYSTEM </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15">
</head>
```

Comment: I try this on my code and it is working. But I have a problem. I create an app that can view this page using web view. It's okay in the beginning but once the page refresh it goes out of the application and open a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think refreshing the page every 15 seconds is good user experience. Why not use a service that's tailored for this kind of work. [Firebase Realtime Database](https://youtu.be/U5aeM5dvUpA?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLmOF_07IayrTntevxtbUxDL) is one very good option, that allows you to have realtime updates in your app. And it's run by Google so that has to be a good thing right.

Otherwise, you'll have to implement your own server-side script to do the updating for you. Let me remind you that **refreshing** the same page over and over again, especially on a mobile network can be **costly** for both you and the user.

Comment: Our application is only applicable inside a spatial range of connection. It only use the wan connection. I think Firebase needs an internet to work.

Comment: Yes, Firebase does need internet, though it does have offline capabilities. Your app working on a WAN makes sense. Now even more since I've just noticed the `raspberry-pi3` tag on your post. If you want live updates though, web sockets are usually the way to go. Here's a [php implementation](http://socketo.me/) of it.

Comment: Noted sir. I will check that